# Not getting the full value passed through the href in the next page

Tags: php

The link tag which is being used in packages.php.

```
<a class='none' href='Tour-details/{$row["seo_title"]}'>
```

And in the next page tour_details.php

```
$abd=$_GET['tour']
```

it should display singapore-package but it is displaying only singapore

Comment: can you further elaborate on what exactly do you need and the example of data you pass to the site so we can recreate the problem?

Comment: share value of `$row["seo_title"]` ?

Comment: where is php syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_GET` superglobal array will contain parameters passed by the GET method on the request.

Ie. those after the `?` in the url

Eg. `<a class='none' href='Tour-details/?tour={$row["seo_title"]}'>`

If you want to pretty print your urls you will need to parse out the requested path using php

Eg.

```
$tour = end(explode('/',parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

Or you could use .htaccess to re write the rules

Eg.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Tour-details/([^/]+)/?$ tour_details.php?tour=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you wants,
if not please share your whole code

packages.php

```
    <?php

    echo "<a class='none' href='tour_details.php?tour=".$row['seo_title']."'>Go</a>";
       //$row['seo_title']="singapore-package"
    ?>
```

tour_details.php

```
<?php

$abd=$_REQUEST['tour'];

echo $abd;
?>
```